# Samsung Book 9 Pro Network Adapter causing BSOD when waking from sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, sleep, wifi-driver

Firstly, this is my first post here. Apologies if this isn't the best place to ask this question.

I bought a new Samsung book 9 pro in January and it's a fantastic laptop apart from one problem. When I put it in to sleep mode each night there's a 1/4 change that when I wake it in the morning the network card will be switched off. It will not list any wi-fi networks. If you switch it on it switches itself off again and if you attempt to diagnose the problem of restart the adapter you get a BSOD every time.

It's a Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A and I have now updated it to the latest driver I can find - 12.0.0.210 released on 15th Jan 2016.

Before I update I would get a BSOD that said DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL but since updating the driver it now says BUGCODE_NDIS_DRIVER when I get the blue screen.

The only way to avoid the BSOD is to reboot the laptop when the problem occurs without trying reboot/diagnose the network adapter. This is no use to me as I still have to save all my work and re-open all my windows in multiple desktops which is driving me crazy.

Unfortunately I can't really contact Samsung about this as bought it from a UK Amazon seller as the laptop hasn't officially been released in this country.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its a buggy driver.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559221(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the error code points to a buggy driver but given that I have a driver released very recently and it's a popular wireless adapter that nobody else seems to be having a problem with, is it possible it's not the driver?

Comment: You would have to debug the crash dump file to know for sure.

Comment: OK, I'll find out how to do that.

Comment: There should be a "minidump" file in  %SystemRoot%\Minidump , which will be  C:\Windows\Minidump on most machines. Actually, since you've crashed several times, there should be several of them. You may also find a memory.dmp file in  %SystemRoot%.

Comment: That folder is currently empty. This may be because the problem hasn't happened for a few days. I found an option in the device settings to stop Windows switching the adapter off when it sleeps. Too early to tell if it's worked but no minidump file unfortunately.